# Using view space of a hidden UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I have three UIViews one below another in my application.The UIView's data is filled by API responses. I want to hide the UIView when it's corresponding API response is nil. I am checking the API response and if it is nil, I am setting [myview setHidden:YES] which hides the view but here is my problem.

Say, if the second view doesn't have any data, it is hidden but the view's coordinate is still occupied and I get big blank space between my first and third view.

To solve this problem, what I did was I used UIView animation method to move the third view in to the second view's coordinate space if second view data is nil.

This works fine for me but this kind of approach adds complexity to my code if I add fourth or fifth view. I am sure there are better solutions than my approach and would be helpful if you can guide me to a better approach than mine.

Thank you

Among the solutions provided I went with the solution provided by Jonah.at.GoDaddy which suited my app. Thank other too for providing great inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a UITableView with 0-3 cells depending on on how many api responses you have?

Comment: Thats a good suggestion and I have lot of subviews within my UIView to handled along with my API response.Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing! You should be able to accomplish what you need by creating a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is check the APIs and only do

```
    UIView *APIView1=[[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:APIView1];
```

when you know the API is available.

Comment: I have used XIB and the views are already there in place and before displaying the API response, I am doing some cleaning up of the response data and showing it in respective views

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good approach for you:
1. Define coordinates for each place you would like to use for placing view and store those coordinates in array A.
2. Each time you add/remove a view to/from superview, add/remove reference to that view to/from array B.
3. After adding/removing references run a loop and assign coordinates from array A to view's frames from array B. Assign them through array ids.
4. Put that loop in UIView animation block.
Now you can use any number of views and remove/add them in which place you want.